# iPhone - Google Text-To-Speech special character URL

Tags: iphone, unicode, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am woking on an iPhone app and I need to integrate Google Text-To-Speech (Google TTS).

It works only for characters from the English alphabet. When trying to form the link (linkTTS) with special characters like Ᾰ, Д, И it does not work anymore.
The code looks like this:

```
NSString *queryTTS = [[NSString alloc] init]; //text to be read
queryTTS = [query stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString *linkTTS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",queryTTS];

NSData *dataTTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkTTS]];

ttsPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataTTS error:nil]; 
[ttsPlayer play];
```

I tried using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding but this is not working because Google TTS is not recognizing this type of URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem while working at an app for Android. I tried with many encoding types but it didn't work.
The thing that finally solved the problem was specifying the "User-Agent" property of the GET request to "Mozilla/5.0". Oh and the encoding type I found best suited is UTF-8. It allows recognition of most special characters, actually any of the ones supported by Google Translate.
Hope this helps